# Clickable image contents with checkbox

Tags: commerce

I have created a site consisting of image galleries, gallery consists of image and a description for it. I want that the user should be able to select multiple image contents as checkbox so that he can add them to cart. After selecting the images I want to compare the details of the selected images.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've added another module. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the  [Commerce product comparison](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_comparison) module

> This module allows you to compare products. This is a familiar feature on commerce website.

There is another module called [Dynamic properties](https://www.drupal.org/project/properties)

> Provides a dynamic properties field that allows to store product properties or similarly structured information. A property consists of an attribute, the name of the property and a value. It belongs to a category.